# Android Radio Button PNG Drawable top

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-radiobutton

[image]

I have a Radio Group. 5 Radio Buttons. The Radio Button's DrawableTop are set as, android:drawableTop="@drawable/Timeline_icon_drawable"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@mipmap/explore_icon_pressed" />

<item android:drawable="@mipmap/explore_icon" />

</selector>
```

How do I make the png smaller?

Comment: smaller means how? u want to resize them? to put in xdpi, xxdpi, mdpi size something like that?

Comment: true that actually worked

Comment: How do I make your answer correct?

Comment: i haven't given my answer yet.. but ill give u descriptive answer. .. then u can upvote if you're satisfied with it

Comment: I have given you answer..you can resize any custom icon or png file for android app easily. read answer... now you can upvote.. if it helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

click on this link.. and download this 9 PATCH RESIZER..

[9PATCH-RESIZER](https://github.com/redwarp/9-Patch-Resizer/releases)

It is specifically designed for developers of android. when you will drag any image on this software it will create every version of drawable images such as
xxxhdpi, xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi.
after customizing png or icon with this software you can use it comfortably in your app.
hope it helps!